# Angular Get Data From JSON to Model And List It

Tags: node.js, json, angular

I'm trying to get data from a JSON using Angular and map it to a model, then show it on a webpage.
I did it buy I'm not getting any results, like the data from JSON cannot be taken or something.

Here's my try:

The JSON:

```
{
    "location": [
        {
            "_id": "5f3567a8d8e66b41d4bdfe5f",
            "lat": "44.4363228",
            "lng": "25.9912305",
            "token": "edb153fb9d8d5628",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

The model:

```
export class Post {
    public _id: string;
    public token: string;
    public lat: string;
    public lng: string;
}
```

Service class:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsService {
    public posts: Post[] = [];
    private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();
    Post: Promise<any>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    private url: string = 'http://localhost:8000/location';

    getPosts() {
        this.http
            .get<{ posts: any[] }>(this.url)
            .pipe(
                map((postData) => {
                    return postData.posts.map((post) => {
                        console.log(this.posts);
                        return {
                            _id: post._id,
                            token: post.token,
                            lat: post.lat,
                            lng: post.lng,
                        };
                    });
                })
            )
            .subscribe((transformedPosts) => {
                this.posts = transformedPosts;
                this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
            });
    }


    getPostUpdateListener() {
        return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
  }
}
```

post-list.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-post-list',
    templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    posts: Post[] = [];
    private postsSub: Subscription;
    result: any;

    constructor(public postsService: PostsService) {
        //dependency-injection
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.postsService.getPosts();

        this.postsSub = this.postsService
            .getPostUpdateListener()
            .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
                this.posts = posts;
            });
    }

    onShow() {
        console.log('TODO');
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.postsSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

post-list.component.html:

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{ post.token }}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p>{{ post.lat }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.lng }}</p>
        <mat-action-row>
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="onShow(post._id)">
                SHOW
            </button>
        </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<p class="info-text mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length <= 0">No posts added yet</p>
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header> <br /><br />

<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>

<br /><br />

<app-post-list></app-post-list>
```

[And here's my result (photo):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPURJ.png)

I also tried to do it in different ways, always getting no result.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error in the image says posts attribute does not exists on postData object which is gotten by get request. Absence of posts attribute is also clear in the JSON you provided.

```
{
    "location": [
        {
            "_id": "5f3567a8d8e66b41d4bdfe5f",
            "lat": "44.4363228",
            "lng": "25.9912305",
            "token": "edb153fb9d8d5628",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

You should completely remove the pipe and it should be fine.